# Javascript - for loops & if-else statements - syntax error

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

//my code (with extra semi-colons)

```
for (var i=1; i < 11; i++) {
    if (i<4) {
        console.log("Your number is between 1 & 3.");
    } else if (i>7) {
        console.log("Your number is between 8 & 10.");
    } else if {
        console.log("Your number is between 4 & 7.");
    }
}
```

I understand I do not need the semi-colon after the (), but I'm confused as to why not. Why exactly is the semi-colon not needed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `else if /* what?? */ {..` if there is no "what??" then just use `else {..`. Also, as a stylistic improvement, the `}`'s and line indents could be placed better ..

Comment: The syntax error has nothing to do with the semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

It's not needed because the JS engine can work out the end of a statement.

Google around for ASI, automatic semi-colon insertion.

Here's one: http://cjihrig.com/blog/the-dangers-of-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion/

Comment: Actually, this is ok answer. Of course, OP syntax error is not related to semi-colons, but - there is question about semi-colons, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

semicolons are used to signal the end of a statement like this `a=b+c;`. The conditional statements like `if` and loops like `for` run on group of statements. So their syntax is not really complete without the group of statements they supposed to run. If you enter `;` after if or for they consider it as a statement and execute it. But their effect wouldn't be applied to block of code after the `;`

Answer (score 0):

You last statement of `else if` doesn't contain any condition, hence you get the syntax error. The compiler marks this right away as well...

your fixed code should look like this:

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  if (i < 4) {
    console.log("Your number is between 1 & 3.");
  } else if (i > 7) {
    console.log("Your number is between 8 & 10.");
  } else {
    console.log("Your number is between 4 & 7.");
  }
}
```